# Automatic Ubuntu 16.04 installation preserving existing partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, automation, preseed, debian-installer

I have seen quite old questions and answers about this subject but the answers were really complicated. So I am hoping that today, we have an easier way to achieve that behavior.

I want to create an automatic installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on a specific partition and want to preserve the others where other OS are installed (or where will be installed).

Note : For the moment I successfully reach to have an automatic installation using a custom partman recipe but it requires to lose my existing partitions.

Comment: can your current recipe be set to use freespace instead of whole disk? Then all you have to do is create unallocated space for it

Comment: @ravery Unfortunately not... I need to repeat this operation several times for several installations on same hard disk...